# Save JQuery.Sortable results to SQL with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

I've been looking at a number of threads about this, but I'm just not getting it.

I have a table that pulls a List from SQL. I'm using JQuery.sortable to sore rows on the client side.

Ideally, I would like to drag and sort the rows in different orders and automatically save them in SQL via my controller using AJAX.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">

    <table id="example" class="table table-responsive table-striped sorted_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Display Order</th>
                <th>Image/Video</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Meta Data</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                order++;
                <tr id="@item.Id">
                    <td>@order</td>
                    <td><img src="~/Images/Home/@item.Location" style="width: 100px;" /></td>
                    <td>@item.Title</td>
                    <td>@item.Meta</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("HomeBgDelete", "Admin", new {id = item.Id})">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="col-sm-4">@Html.ActionLink("Add Another", "HomeBG", "Admin")</div>
    <div><button id="submit-list" class="btn btn-default">Save Order</button></div>


</div>


<script>
    // Sortable rows
    $('.sorted_table').sortable({
        containerSelector: 'table',
        itemPath: '> tbody',
        itemSelector: 'tr',
        placeholder: '<tr class="placeholder"/>',
    });


</script>
```

I've looked at one method, which iterates through the DOM and builds an array of the new order and then passes the array through an AJAX call to the controller to process. I've tried some of that code with no success.

Any help would be great!

Comment: I would suggest the [update](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change) callback. At which method did you look?

Comment: Thanks Felix. So update is the event... how would you gather the element ids and order? If you have seen a good example, would love to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough idea (relating to the comments under your questions), you can iterate over the table rows in the [update](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) callback of Sortable. There you can access the current element, get ids, other attributes and indices, depending on what you need.

```
var ids = [];
$('#example tbody').sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    $('#example tbody tr').each( function(index) {
      ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: For some reason I'm not able to hit the function via update.    // Sortable rows
    $('.sorted_table').sortable({
        containerSelector: 'table',
        itemPath: '> tbody',
        itemSelector: 'tr',
        placeholder: '<tr class="placeholder"/>',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            alert('you just changed it');
        }
    });